# Redraw lots of objects on Canvas HTML

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, html, canvas

Is there a quick and efficient way to move lots of objects in `canvas`? Basically if there are around 1000 objects and I want to move all of them at once to emulate scrolling, it is very slow to redraw every single object by calling `drawImage()` 1000+ times.

Is there anyway to optimize this? I have an example link of the problem (and that's only with 100 objects): http://craftyjs.com/isometric/

Comment: Are the images static (non-animating)?

Comment: I can't guarantee that but if there is an optimization for static images, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Props for the Minecraft artwork :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw all objects on a second, off-screen canvas and then only blit the whole canvas (`drawImage()` accepts canvas element).

However, if you're targeting desktop browsers, then this shouldn't be necessary. I've [implemented tile engine](http://pornel.net/gamejam/) ([source](https://github.com/pornel/Enterprise)) that simply redraws whole scene and naive implementation turned out to be pretty fast.

Comment: Yes, it seems my automatic redraw regions which were meant to speed things up, is making it worse. Though I think it will benefit when only a few objects are moving.

Answer (score 4):

Since canvas doesn't provide *fast* low level bitmap copying it's hard to do stuff in multiple layers and scroll for example the whole background at once and then only render the edges.

So what can you do? In short, **nothing.** Especially not when scrolling, sure you can do tricks with multiple canvases when you have a more or less static background but for moving objects there are hardly any performance improving tricks.

So, you've go to wait for Hardware Acceleration shipping in all majors browsers, I know this sounds ridiculous but I'm too waiting for that :/

The problem is that the `canvas` was never designed for game stuff. It was designed as, well, basically some kind of on the fly drawing thing, guess the designers had Photoshop clones in mind, but definitely not games, let alone the fact that there's no **fast** clear operation proves that, there's not even optimization in place when clearing the whole canvas with the same color.

Comment: FFFFUUUUUU. Will just have to optimize 'til I can't optimize no more. Good thing about my little engine is it works with DOM and canvas.

Answer (score 3):

If the images are already composited, not moving relative to one another, and defined by a rectangular region, then using [`canvas.drawImage()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage) with a canvas as the first parameter and drawing to a sub-region should be significantly faster than re-drawing all the objects.

You could also just layer multiple canvases and slide the top canvas with the objects in HTML to scroll them.

**Edit**: Having really looked at your example, it seems to me that it should be implemented similar to Google Maps: create tiles of canvases and slide them left/right on the HTML page; once a canvas has been slid off the screen entirely (for example, off the left edge), move it to the other side (to the right edge) and re-use it for drawing. With this you will only need to re-draw whatever objects overlap the canvases that are moving on the edges.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this problem was I had 10 squares on my screen and I wanted to animate them on a white background. So I drew a white rectangle over the canvas to clear the canvas so the animation would work. Does that make sense?

@Ivo By the way I read on http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html that canvas was made for applications like games because it was a solution to get rid of the dependency on a  external engine. Canvas is built in so it's kind of like a flash player built into your browser powered by JavaScript. I think it's fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tiled rendering.
http://www.gamesfrommars.fr/demojsv2/ (better viewed with Chrome)